# how to use rails path in href for jquerymobile button

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, href, erb

I am working in rails using jquery.mobile button.(/view/sessions/new.html.erb)

I have a hard code path which I tried to change to rails routes path.
Here original hard code:

```
 <a href="/password_resets/new" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-mini="true">Forgotten password?</a>
```

My button is OK as expected in 2 nd button
[image]

The problem when replaced with rails path (from rake routes) is the link. It only work at the text "Forgotten password", not the button itself.
Here that code:

```
<div class="actions" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-mini="true"><%= link_to 'Forgotten password?', new_password_reset_path %></div>
```

How to use rails path inside href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
<%= link_to 'Forgotten password?', new_password_reset_path, data: {icon: 'info', mini: 'true', role: 'button'} %>
```

Comment: Greate it work!.  I still like to know if I can call path in href eg: href="/password_resets/new" with href= ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use rails path inside href:

```
<a href="<%= new_password_reset_path %>" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-mini="true">Forgotten password?</a>
```